# Validation of text box only for number in 22.22 format

Tags: jquery, html

I need to validate textbox in jquery or html, only for number.Do not allow to enter number greater than 99.99
If I enter number 54 then textbox should show 54.00
If I enter number 54. then textbox should show 54.00
If I enter number 54.0 then textbox should show 54.00

if I try to enter 100 then textbox should not accept it.
thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the working Fiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5672/)

```
 $("#quantity").blur(function (e) {
 if(+this.value >= 100){
         $("#errmsg").html("Enter less than 100").show().fadeOut("slow");
       $(this).val(99.00)
     }
  else{
   $(this).val(parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2));
  }
})
```

Or you can either use the `Jquery UI Plugin`

[Numeric Textbox Demo](http://transtatic.com/plugin/numericInput.htm)

Comment: superb code  . thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

below code accepts number and validates it as a Decimal;

```
Enter Decimal Number:<input type="text" name="num"> 
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="isDecimal()">
```

Paste the following within you page header tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function isDecimal(str) {
        str = document.getElementById('num').value;
        if (isNaN(str) || str.indexOf(".") < 0) {
            alert("Invalid");
        }
        else {
            str = parseFloat(str);
            document.getElementById('num').value = str;
            if (str > 99.99) {
                alert("must be less than 99.99");
            }
        }
    }
    function validate() {
        var dec = document.form.num.value;
        if (dec == "") {
            alert("Please enter Decimal.");
            form.num.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (isDecimal(dec) == false) {
            num = "";
            form.num.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

the above validates the number as integer, and also changes text to Decimal.